# Convert any file to binary string and from binary to file

Tags: javascript, java, php, algorithm, binary

I am trying to create 2 algorithms via java or php or javascript (I know these languages, so you can use them to answer my question). The first algorithm should take any file (exe, mp3, txt, png, docx etc.) and convert it to a binary string of 0 and 1. And the second algorithm should convert a string of 0 and 1 to a file.

Is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

I tried to develop that:

```
 $buffer = file_get_contents("image.png");
 $length = filesize("image.png");

 if (!$buffer || !$length) {
   die("Reading error\n");
 }

 $_buffer = '';
 for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   $_buffer .= sprintf("%08b", ord($buffer[$i]));
 }

 echo $_buffer."<br>";

 $nb = "";
 for($i = 0;$i<strlen($_buffer)/8;$i++) {
     $sub = substr($_buffer, $i*8,$i*8+8);
     $nb .= chr(bindec($sub));
 }
 $new = fopen("aaaimage.png","wb");
 $w = fwrite($new,$nb);
```

It works only when it convert to binary, but when it create the new file, its not working, it create a file with the same size but the file is not work as it should. The new image (In this code the file is an image) show an error when I am trying to open it, the error is that the file may be damaged.

Comment: Have you done any research or made any attempt?

Comment: everything is possible, but what have you tried ?!

Comment: @NewToJS Yes, I searched a lot on Google, and I tried to program something myself but it failed. I have no knowledge of such conversions.

Comment: If you tried something but couldn't get it to work, then show us what you've tried and what the errors are and we might be able to help you with that code. This is not a free coding service where we just code it for you. Show us that you actually made an effort.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I tried, I create code which get the binary from file, but I dont know how to convert it again to a file

Comment: Then i suggest you share your attempt, this will give people something to work with/debug and also narrow down the choice of language. Your question is too board and doesn't display/include the relevant information.

Comment: @NewToJS look again, I edited the question

Comment: @MagnusEriksson look, I edited the question.

Comment: @ShaiLA, [please don't edit your question to include the correct answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved). Instead, [add an answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Chris when I am trying to accept my answer I got the message: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: @ShaiLA, yes, you will need to wait a little while before accepting your own answer. Thank you for modifying your question and adding an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I discovered that the problem was in the code. Just small mistake using substr func.
So, the correct code is:

```
 $buffer = file_get_contents("image.png");
 $length = filesize("image.png");

 if (!$buffer || !$length) {
   die("Reading error\n");
 }

 $_buffer = '';
 for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   $_buffer .= sprintf("%08b", ord($buffer[$i]));
 }

 echo $_buffer."<br>";

 $nb = "";
 for($i = 0;$i<strlen($_buffer)/8;$i++) {
     $sub = substr($_buffer, $i*8,8);
     $nb .= chr(bindec($sub));
 }
 $new = fopen("aaaimage.png","wb");
 $w = fwrite($new,$nb);
```